# Labels missing in barplot

Tags: r, bar-chart

I have a dataset that I would like to visualize with `barplot()` .  My question is, why do some labels *not* show when appended with `text()` and how does one solve this issue?

For example this is my table

```
table(test$Freq)

   2    3    4    5    6    7    8    9   10   11   12   14   16   44 
6338 2544 1072  394  102   29   11    9    5    2    3    1    1    1
```

And the following barplot will miss the first label:

```
barplot(table(test$Freq))
text(x = xx, y = test$Freq, label = test$Freq, pos = 3, cex = 0.8, col = "red")
```

[image]

Comment: Because the text is plotted "outside" the graph. Try this: barplot(table(test$Freq),ylim=c(0,8000)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like the text is being plotted outside of your graph.

Try adjusting the `ylim` value when you call `barplot`. This should solve your problem.